# Woocommerce Order By controls have disappeared

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I was editing my child template in Wordpress with Woocommerce. There used to be an order by input control to order my products according to various categories. However, all of a sudden it has disappeared and I am not sure what I did.

I disabled all css and functions, and even switched to another theme, but it is still gone. I checked the code and the hook 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' is still being called.

Can anyone suggest where I can go about deducing this. I also checked all of wp-admin panel and could not find any option to enable or disable this. I only have five products added. Does this make a difference?

Comment: *"I was editing my child template in Wordpress"*, you mean Woocommerce templates in your child theme or some php files in your child theme? Sometimes things remaining in WC Transients. You can clear them in Woocommerce >System status > Tools (tab) > WC Transients. Try that… And please could you edit your question to make it more clear.

Comment: I meant I have a wordpress website with the woocommerce plugin activated. I created a Child of the Storefront Theme and made some changes to the template files and added/removed some functions from some of the hooks.


I tried what you suggested, but it did not work. Due to some reason, it is not showing the drop down that orders the Product Page by Date, Price, Category, etc. I can see the action that populates the order by drop down being called, and it does not show even if I change the theme.

Comment: UPDATE: When I simply go to the shop page, the order by does not show, but it does when I search for a term and go. I guess it needs a query before it can order. Perhaps, I may have disabled product filter, or some similar thing when I edited the themes. Thoughts?

Comment: So you mean you are using a *child theme* of Storefront. So you have copy inside this child theme the "templates" folder of woocommerce plugin (and rename it *woocommerce*). You have modificated those templates (located in your child theme folder) to fit your needs. Are you sure that in your woocommerce plugin folder, the *templates* folder (and all the files inside it) exist and that is remaining untouched? I ask that because you say that the problem still there, even if you change of theme…

Comment: Wordpress is on a shared host and I don't have access to its woocommerce folder. The order by does come, if I go to the shop page, via a search. However, earlier, it used to show the order by down, if I simply visit too. Not sure what happened.

Comment: Strange, you mean you can't access to your wordpress folder by FTP? Even on a shared hosting (normally) you can access to all the files of your hosting plan (all the files of your website).

Comment: Hmm.. I am not sure about that, but I have only been uploading to wp-content folder.

Comment: you have to check that, because it's the only way…